# how to open a collapsible panel after button click

Tags: javascript, php

how to open a collapsible panel after button click. button is on the first page then the collapsible panel in on the second page.

here's my collapsible panel details.

```
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Medicine
        </a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="transaction.php" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h7>Medicine Type : </h7></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename">
        <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>
```

this my script code - not working

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#collapseone').collapseone({
    toggle: true
    });
    </script>
```

where should i put the script code on the first or second page?

Comment: Where do you find the script you have written??

Comment: "button is on the first page then the collapsible panel in on the second page". what do you mean by this? a script doesn't work across different pages.

Comment: can you help me Steven Manuel on how to do that?

Comment: I'd recommend you find a tutorial on how JS / jQuery works.

Comment: the panel is closed in default.

Answer (score 0):

code something like this.. when i click a button in page 1 i will set an item name as abc , in ur page 2 it will check whether that item name is abc , if it is abc then ur particular panel will be displayed.

page 1:

```
<input type="button" id="btnQueryString" onClick="submit()" value="Send" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
 {
       //write ur code what u want
        var myvalue = "abc";
'<%Session["name"] = "' + myvalue + '"; %>';
 }
```

page 2 :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var newvalue = '<%= Session["name"] %>';
  if( newvalue == abc)
{
   document.getElementById('Panel1').style.display = "block";
}
else
{
 document.getElementById('Panel1').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

In page1 i have written a method called submit, this method is used to send value to page2 just to notify that button is clicked, and i will call this method in button like onClick="submit".

In page2 , first i will check the session value, if button is clicked in page1 the value will be :abc: or else it will be blank. So if value is abc , i will display the panel.

Comment: `localStorage` didn't work on older browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: @Anirudh am confused with this '<%Session["name"] = "' + Name + '"; %>'; the "name" with small n? what value should it be?

Comment: name is just a variable to store a value in sessions, u can write anything there, Name is also a variable which i have called above. for example, var myval= "abc"; '<%Session["name"] = "' + myval+ '"; %>';

Comment: or u can write directly like '<%Session["name"] = " abc "; %>';

Comment: did u get any idea here ?, its simple, when u click a button, i will just pass a value to another page , so that the another page will get to know that button has been clicked. Here i will write like if i get any value from that page , i will display my panel